# Count total number of occurrences of given list of integers in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

How do I count the number of times the same integer occurs?

My code so far:

```
def searchAlgorithm (target, array):
    i = 0 #iterating through elements of target list
    q = 0 #iterating through lists sublists via indexes
    while q < 4:
        x = 0 #counting number of matches
        for i in target:
            if i in array[q]:
                x += 1
            else:
               x == 0
        print(x)
        q += 1


a = [8, 12, 14, 26, 27, 28]
b = [[4, 12, 17, 26, 30, 45], [8, 12, 19, 24, 33, 47], [3, 10, 14, 31, 39, 41], [4, 12, 14, 26, 30, 45]]

searchAlgorithm(a, b)
```

The output of this is:

```
2
2
1
3
```

What I want to achieve is counting the number of times '1', '2' '3' matches occurs.

I have tried:

```
v = 0
if searchAlgorithm(a, b) == 2:
    v += 1
print(v)
```

But that results in `0`

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is it that you are trying to do exactly, and what is the difficulty?

Comment: Oh. So, yeah, your functions doesn't *do anything except print*. you probably want to accumulate your results into a list and return that list form your function. As an aside, you probably don't want to use a `while` loop. You already seem to know how to use a for-loop, so just stick with that when you know how many times you are goping to iterate

Comment: I am wanting to count the number of times a match has occurred.

Comment: So do you want to count the number of twos, threes and ones in the output? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You forgot to return `q` out of your `searchAlgorithm` function. That is why v is never incremented. `None` (no return) is never equal to 2.

Comment: It's hard to explain, so apologies. If the comparisons between a and b results in 3 matches I want to have a counter that increments. So I'm not counting the number of matches per comparison. I'm counting the number of times a match a of 3 or 2 or 4 has occurred.

Comment: OK, yeah. As I explained, your function simply prints, and you return `None`. You need to grok the basics of the difference between return and print. You want to accumulate your results in some container, like a list, and return that list from your function. Then, count the results in that list.

Comment: Yes i know its printing instead of returning this is so I can see what is going on (really debugging). It wouldn't print when working correctly.

Comment: ... OK then *why dont your return something*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use intersection of sets to find elements that are common in both lists. Then you can get the length of the sets. Here is how it looks:

```
num_common_elements = (len(set(a).intersection(i)) for i in b)
```

You can then iterate over the generator `num_common_elements` to use the values. Or you can cast it to a list to see the results:

```
print(list(num_common_elements))
[Out]: [2, 2, 1, 3]
```

If you want to implement the intersection functionality yourself, you can use the sum method to implement your own version. This is equivalent to doing `len(set(x).intersection(set(y))`

```
sum(i in y for i in x)
```

This works because it generates values such as `[True, False, False, True, True]` representing where the values in the first list are present in the second list. The `sum` method then treats the `True`s as 1s and `False`s as 0s, thus giving you the size of the intersection set

Comment: I am trying to avoid the use of sets, as I'm wanting to write it as an algorithm. So while sets would work it's not my preferred solution.

Comment: Note, your `sum` and `set` based solutions *are not equivalent*. As an aside, you don't need `set(i)`, the `.intersection` method takes any iterable.

Comment: Yes you are correct. They would only be equivalent if there are no elements that are duplicates in both lists. In which case, the `sum` solution is more correct

Answer (score 0):

This is based on what I understand from your question. Probably you are looking for this:

```
from collections import Counter

def searchAlgorithm (target, array):
    i = 0 #iterating through elements of target list
    q = 0 #iterating through lists sublists via indexes
    lst = []
    while q < 4:
        x = 0 #counting number of matches
        for i in target:
            if i in array[q]:
                x += 1
            else:
               x == 0
        lst.append(x)
        q += 1
    print(Counter(lst))


a = [8, 12, 14, 26, 27, 28]
b = [[4, 12, 17, 26, 30, 45], [8, 12, 19, 24, 33, 47], [3, 10, 14, 31, 39, 41], [4, 12, 14, 26, 30, 45]]

searchAlgorithm(a, b)
# Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some for their helpful feedback, I have since come up a more simplified solution that does exactly what I want.

By storing the `results` of the matches in a list, I can then return the list out of the `searchAlgorithm` function and simple use `.count()` to count all the matches of a specific number within the list.

```
def searchAlgorithm (target, array):
    i = 0 
    q = 0
    results = []
    while q < 4:
        x = 0 #counting number of matches
        for i in target:
            if i in array[q]:
                x += 1
            else:
               x == 0
        results.append(x)
        q += 1
    return results

a = [8, 12, 14, 26, 27, 28]
b = [[4, 12, 17, 26, 30, 45], [8, 12, 19, 24, 33, 47], [3, 10, 14, 31, 39, 41], [4, 12, 14, 26, 30, 45]]

searchAlgorithm(a, b)

d2 = (searchAlgorithm(winNum, lotto).count(2))
```